# Android wear emulator not firing onSensorChanged event

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, wear-os

I have a very simple watch app which tries to detect movement:

```
package com.example.watchapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.TriggerEvent;
import android.hardware.TriggerEventListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {


    private static final String TAG = "CUSTOM_TAG";
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        List<Sensor> deviceSensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        for (Sensor deviceSensor : deviceSensors) {
            System.out.println("sensor : " + deviceSensor.getName());
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        int sensorType = event.sensor.getType();
        switch (sensorType) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                float valueX = event.values[0];
                float valueY = event.values[1];
                float valueZ = event.values[2];
                System.out.println("Sensor Changed value:");
                Log.d(TAG, "Sensor Changed value:" + valueX + ":" + valueY + ":" + valueZ);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {



    }

}
```

Using the emulator simulate movement on the phone:

[image]

The `onSensorChanged` event does not appear to be fired as "Sensor Changed value:" is not printed to Android Studio console. Is there a specific emulator for a wearable app I should use to simulate movement on a watch app? Or have I not coded the app correctly?

Comment: I am not sure the sensor emulator works on Android Wear devices. I know it works very well on an Android emulator, but I have never tested it on Android Wear.

Answer (score -1):

I mistakenly assumed to use Android Studio to develop the app for Samsung device. Samsung has it's own IDE environment for watch OS - Tizen.